# Navigation Bar in UIPopover

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

in my splitviewcontroller iPad app I show a custom popover (which loads the rootviewController). How to show not only the table view, but also a navigationbar on top of it (to show the table title "Categories").

Here is my app:

[image]

My code to show the popover:

```
- (IBAction)showPopover:(UIButton *)sender {
if([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible])
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    return;
}

// Build a custom popover view
TemplatesAppDelegate *delegate = (TemplatesAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// Create a popover controller
self.popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:delegate.rootViewController] autorelease];

// Present the popover view non-modal at the pressed button's position
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a whole UINavigationController with all the functionalities, you can do like

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:delegate.rootViewController];

self.popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController] autorelease];
[navController release];
```

Or if you want just a navigation bar you can add to your popovercontroller.

```
UINavigationBar *tableViewNavigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)];
[self.popoverController addSubView:tableViewNavigationBar];
```

I didn't tested the code, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
CNYAssetTypeViewController *avc=[[CNYAssetTypeViewController alloc] init];
if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    UINavigatinoController *nv=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:avc];
    self.assetTypeControllerPopover=[[UIPopOverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:nv];
    self.assetTypeControllerPopover.delegat=self;
    avc.title=@"CNY";
    [self.assetTypeControllerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopOverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}else{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:avc animated:YES];    
}
```